# getUserMedia() Camera Focus

Tags: jquery, getusermedia

I would like to ask if there is a function for camera focus using getUserMedia? I'm using QuaggaJS project - https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/examples/live_w_locator.html

What I would like to do is to have a focus on camera because it is a little blurry and it can't detect the barcode. Does anyone know if it is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firsly - though perhaps bad practice here - I will link to why MediaCapture might be blurry or grainy than expected:

In short: MediaCapture does a lot of transformations on the media source which may cause blury or grainy images. The MediaConstraints object which is passed to getUserMedia does not allow you to specify where to focus. This is Browser dependant and typically should be around the center.

To solve this use ImageCapture:

> The ImageCapture API enables control over camera features such as
>   zoom, brightness, contrast, ISO and white balance. Best of all, Image
>   Capture allows you to access the full resolution capabilities of any
>   available device camera or webcam. Previous techniques for taking
>   photos on the Web have used video snapshots, which are lower
>   resolution than that available for still images.

To solve your problem:

If QuaggaJS does not use ImageCapture then no it is not possible. If it does you can solve this via UX and a zoom slider. Below is information on how to achieve this with ImageCapture (still images). MediaCapture (video feed) does not allow this functionality. You could use ImageCapture and have a button such as "Manual Mode" which allows a user to pick the correct zoom to take the photo.

You could also "emulate" a camera by having an update loop doing n ImageCaptures per update.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/imagecapture

And here is an example on how to use it/polyfill: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/imagecapture-polyfill

Makesure you use the latest getUserMedia polyfills which handle crossplatform support: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webrtc-adapter

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If focus is not working very well.You can do testing with locate : false. Default value for locate is true.

```js
{
  locate: false,
  area: { // defines rectangle of the detection/localization area
    top: "30%",   // top offset
    right: "30%",  // right offset
    left: "30%",   // left offset
    bottom: "30%"  // bottom offset
  }
}
```

Adjust area according to your need.

Comment: Hi, iv'e tried to update the locate: false and it is still not working and still blurry.